# elementary OS application development databases?

Tags: applications, development, design, metadata

Is there any resources/documentation on which database can be use to save application input data. I am trying to build an invoicing application for elementary OS Loki.

Answer (score 7):

Check out the [developer](https://developer.elementary.io) section of elementary's website. They offer advice on many components you can use to build elementary-style applications. Specifically, they recommend GDA for managing databases, which has documentation available on [Valadoc](http://valadoc.org/libgda-5.0/Gda).

Comment: Hey do you know if Glade can be used to create you components,grids,windows?

Comment: Glade isn't covered in the developer docs, but it should work just fine. Elementary OS apps are built with GTK+, which is what Glade uses.